# A Batch Script To Resize Images

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file, jpeg, image-resizing

I'm looking for some help in writing a batch script to resize a bunch of .jpg images.

I don't have much experience with batch scripts. But this task will be preformed on a windows machine & so I thought a batch script might be a good way to go.

I'm always interested in hearing alternative ideas & approaches, or being made aware of elements I haven't thought of.

Below I have listed the basic steps/needs of the script:

```
1) The images are located in a folder & are all(or should be) 500 x
500.

2) I need copy & past the images to a new folder, where they will be
resized to 250 x 250.

3) I then need to repeat step 2 but this time resize to 125 x 125.
```

Comment: Might be useful http://askubuntu.com/questions/135477/how-can-i-scale-all-images-in-a-folder-to-the-same-width

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use [Image Resizer for Windows](http://www.bricelam.net/ImageResizer/):

[image]

[image]

Comment: For posterity Image Resizer is now part of the resurrected Microsoft PowerToys https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys

Answer (score 32):

Once you install [ImageMagick for Windows](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows), you can use [`magick` command-line tool](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/mogrify.php), e.g.

```
magick.exe mogrify -resize 250x250 -path 250x250/ *.png *.jpg
magick.exe mogrify -resize 125x125 -path 125x125/ *.png *.jpg
```

Note: Make sure your `magick.exe` command is in your `PATH` system variable and you're pointing to the existing or created the destined folders (e.g. `mkdir 250x250/ 125x125/` in above case).

For Linux/Ubuntu, see: [How to easily resize images via command-line?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1164/78223)

Comment: Just make sure the folder exists before you run it.

Comment: Before running this, run `mkdir 250x250` and `mkdir 125x125`

Comment: Upvoting this, since the question specifically asked for doing it from a batch script - ImageMagick would allow this, and is a tried and tested, popular tool for automating image operations.

Answer (score 19):

you can check [**`scale.bat`**](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/imageProcessing/scale.bat) which can resize images without a need of installing additional software - it uses only the windows built-in capabilities:

```
@echo off
set "source_folder=c:\images"
set "result_folder_1=c:\res1"
set "result_folder_2=c:\res2"

for %%a in ("%source_folder%\*jpg") do (
   call scale.bat -source "%%~fa" -target "%result_folder_1%\%%~nxa" -max-height 250 -max-width 250 -keep-ratio no -force yes
)

for %%a in ("%source_folder%\*jpg") do (
   call scale.bat -source "%%~fa" -target "%result_folder_2%\%%~nxa" -max-height 125 -max-width 125 -keep-ratio no -force yes
)
```

Check also [this](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Resize-Image-File-f6dd4a56).

Comment: I like this solution best. It is simple, uses what is already on the system and also provides good example on how to interface with the system to extend or do something else. Good Job!

Comment: I'm sorry to say, but the quality of resized PNG files is low - it seems it uses the simplest "nearest neighbor" algorithm.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady - thanks for the note. Though with automating the existing windows tools I can't do more.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to do it on the command line specifically, perhaps so you can automate it, there is no specific command in Batch that is made for image manipulation. You can code up something in a JScript or another language and run it from the command line, but why do that when there are mature tools already available for this task?

I recommend [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php).

Get the portable Windows binary, then you can use magick.exe to do what you want pretty easily. For example, to resize (by half) all the png images in folder 1 to folder 2:

```
@echo off
if not exist 2 md 2
for %%a in (1\*.png) do "path\to\magick.exe" -resize 50x50% "1\%~nxa" "2\%~nxa"
```

Comment: Since this answer was posted, ImageMagick's exe is now called `magick.exe` not `convert.exe`.

Comment: Changed convert to magick

Comment: Since you use ImageMagick, it may be wiser to use the correct resize procedure... https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/#resize_colorspace that means using:   for %%a in (1\*.png) do "path\to\magick.exe "1\%~nxa" -colorspace RGB -resize 50x50% -colorspace sRGB "2\%~nxa"

Comment: My comment is valid for downscaling. If you upscale images, stick with the commendline of the answer.

Comment: "but why do that when there are mature tools already available for this task" - because you may not want to make a tool that weighs an additional 77 MB due to ImageMagick. In case of JPG files, there is a simple tool http://www.rw-designer.com/picture-resize .

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Someone else who uses RW-Designer software? Never thought I'd see the day!